# MYSQL Trim function using on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql codes which i need to do that trim and leading with PHP, anyone know how to write below logics with PHP code.

```
LEFT(TRIM(LEADING 'DHL ' FROM CONT_NAAM),20) 


TRIM(LEADING 'DHL JVGL' FROM CONT_NAAM)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
substr(preg_replace('/^(DHL )+/', '', $cont_naam), 1, 20)
```